# git clone --bare does not include branch master

Tags: git

I'm trying to establish workflows for creating new projects and for setting old projects to be version controlled through Git. It is finally all making sense, except for one step. When I create a new project, initialize Git in it and do an initial commit I then do a `git clone --bare ./myproject //myserver/myshare/myproject.git`. I then set up a remote, `git remote add origin //myserver/myshare/myproject.git`. These seem to work fine. But, when I do `git branch -a`, it does not show there being a master branch on the remote.

The way I am getting around this right now is, I just `git clone //myserver/myshare/myproject.git` to a different location and the remote is already set up, and the master branch is present on the remote. I have no idea what could be wrong, especially since the only difference it seems is which way the remote is set up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. From the `git clone` man page:

```
   --bare
       Make a bare GIT repository. That is, instead of creating <directory> and placing the administrative files in <directory>/.git, make the <directory>
       itself the $GIT_DIR. This obviously implies the -n because there is nowhere to check out the working tree. Also the branch heads at the remote are
       copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to refs/remotes/origin/. When this option is used, neither remote-tracking
       branches nor the related configuration variables are created.
```

Bare repositories don't map the `master` commit pointer to `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but they don't have to. Bare repos are [vital when setting up remotes that others might `push` to or `pull` from,](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html) but [they aren't where you do day-to-day dev work.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985045/877115) It sounds like you have an `origin`. Unless you're setting up another remote, stick with `git clone //myserver/myshare/myproject.git` for your local repository.

Comment: Are you saying that my existing process is correct then? I get that all the merging and work is supposed to be done locally, but I want //myserver to be the centralized repo where everyone can push and pull changes, and I'd like for us to have tiered branches (master being releases, and then a testing branch where features are integrated before eventually making it to master --both of these branches available from the repo). Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, if you want `//myserver` to be the centralized repo from which everyone can `push` or `pull`, you should be set up just fine. If you want to put new branches on it, branch them in your local repository and push them to origin. E.g. `git checkout -B testing master && git push origin testing`

Answer (score 0):

From `git branch` help:

> -a, --all : list both remote-tracking and local branches
>
> -l, --list : list branch names
>
> -r, --remotes : act on remote-tracking branches

It seems that there's no option to list the **branches on the remote repository**. But the branch is there if it was in your local repository during bare cloning. The trick is to notice the wording here. *Remote-tracking*. And what `git branch -a` does is to show you, along with your local branches, any branch you may have set up to **track a remote branch** - which by the way is not what `git remote add <name> <url>` command does. This just sets up a *remote*. No *branch tracking*.

So, in order to actually do what you were actually trying, you need something like this:

`(somehow)cd //myserver/myshare/myproject.git && git branch --list`

Or you can check in //myserver/myshare/myproject.git/refs/heads or in //myserver/myshare/myproject.git/packed-refs to confirm that the branch exist.

And finally, to set up a shared repository, and not a repository to work on, the `git clone --bare` is the proper way to do it. Without the `--bare` option, after cloning git checks out a working tree of the HEAD branch of the cloned repository which normally is not desired nor makes sense on servers.