# Merging commits in bare repositories using JGit

Tags: jgit

I have a bare Git repository. Let's say I have some content in branch `master` and the head is pointing at commit "C1".

`test.txt` at C1 contains

```
line-1
```

Now, I create a new branch ref `R1` and add a new commit `C11` with its parent commit being `C1` (head of `R1`).

`test.txt` at C11 contains

```
line-1
line-2
line-3
```

I pulled `master` and see that a new commit C2 is added.
It contains `test.txt` as

```
line-1
line-2
```

Now, I want to merge C2 with C11 and create a new commit.

The issue I am facing is while merging.

I think this should auto-merge without any conflicts.

[image: Bare Git Merge Scenario]

To merge:

```
Merger merger = MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE.newMerger(git.getRepository(), true);
merger.merge('C2', 'C11');
```

Here, the merge result is conflicted. But ideally, it should have been a non-conflicting auto-merge.

The JGit API for merging `org.eclipse.jgit.merge.MergeAlgorithm#merge` has the following input:

```
base

line-1

ours

line-1
line-2

theirs

line-1
line-2
line-3
```

What could be missing here / Anything special needs to be done while merging for bare repositories?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the ref you created? Is it a branch?

Comment: Yes.  `R1` is a branch ref.

Comment: I’m not convinced that bare repos can solve merge conflicts as they do not have a working tree to resolve them.

Comment: I was wondering how Github manages it. I guess Github creates bare repositories.

Comment: They do? I thought github forces the user to correct merge conflicts?

Comment: For merge conflicts, yes. But for non-conflicting changes, it auto-merges the files. In my post, I am more interested merging non-conflicting changes. For example, `test.txt` content in `master` and `R1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846057/989920 does this help?

Comment: Although jgit generally *duplicates* the things Git does, jgit is not Git and whatever answers you get here will be specific to jgit only, so I've snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Comment: To merge non-conflicting commits, you could use an 'in-core' merger, created with `newMerger(repo, true)`, which doesn't touch the work dir. It should give you the merged tree from which you can construct a commit. JGit also provides low-level API to create commits. You could use the `MergeCommand` as a template to build a bare repo merger. A few details noted here may also help: https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/

Comment: With 'in-core' merger, it seems merge fails even when both commits contain auto-mergeable content. For example, in the above post, `test.txt` is auto-mergeable. Even for this, I get conflict during the merge. Does 'in-core' work only when both commits contain changes in different files and are not conflicting? Or am I missing anything here? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my post with some more details of the merge conflict scenario.